# Setting QML context fail

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qvariant, qqmlcontext

I am trying to connect a C++ class to QML but I am facing a problem, the following errors appear when compile.

I am adding an image to show the errors:

[image]

I am using a simple class just to test if my code works , here is the code
testing.h:

```
#ifndef TESTING_H
#define TESTING_H


class Testing
{
public:
    Testing();
    void trying();
};

#endif // TESTING_H
```

and testing.cpp:

```
#include "testing.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Testing::Testing()
{

}
void Testing::trying()
{
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
}
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "testing.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlContext* context= engine.rootContext();
    Testing a;
    context->setContextProperty("test",&a);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

and main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: test.tryout();
       }
}
```

Comment: what is tryout?

Comment: a method from texting , sorry i didn't mention

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: trying == tryout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html):

> Context properties can hold either QVariant or QObject* values. This
>   means custom C++ objects can also be injected using this approach, and
>   these objects can be modified and read directly in QML. Here, we
>   modify the above example to embed a QObject instance instead of a
>   QDateTime value, and the QML code invokes a method on the object
>   instance:

From the above you can conclude that the class should inherit from QObject, in addition if you want to call the function try you must precede Q_INVOKABLE in the declaration, this I show in the following code:

**testing.h**

```
#ifndef TESTING_H
#define TESTING_H

#include <QObject>

class Testing: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Testing(QObject *parent=0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void trying();
};

#endif // TESTING_H
```

**testing.cpp**

```
#include "testing.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Testing::Testing(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{

}

void Testing::trying()
{
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
}
```

You should also change from `tryout()` to `trying()` in the qml file.